# Users cannot delete Public icons

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, security, permissions

We are rolling out new laptops to my company and we are no longer setting the user as a Local Admin. Instead, the user will be a part of the "Users" group. While I am not a part of the team that dictates desktop policy, I am assisting with the roll out. One issue that some people I have set up have encountered is they are not able to delete icons on their desktop that are a part of the Public profile and thus available to all users. If I were in their shoes, this would annoy me as well. Is there any simple way to grant them this ability?

Answer (score 2):

Give the "Users" group full control over the `c:\users\Public\Desktop` folder.

Comment: This is an option. We could add this to our image for future machines. But, it would be very difficult to do this on machine already rolled out. I'll see if there is a way to push this out.

Comment: @Nik GPO can do that for you simply enough **Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > File System**

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to configure the public profile to suit your needs. Unneeded shortcuts can be easily deleted with a batch file which is run by an admin account while the machines are being configured.

Comment: We want the user to have the choice. A lot of users want the icons, but not all.

Comment: @Nik, in that situation I move the icons from public profile to the default profile. That way they get added to each user's profile the first time they log on and they can do what they want with them. Again, this is easily scripted.